# Delete Google Chrome's tab history

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, history, google-chrome-extensions

After browsing the web for a while, I want to delete my history.  So I press
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> keys, and click the **Edit** items on the blue bar at the top of the page. Then I select the checkboxes for the items I want to remove. Then I click **remove selected items**.

When I go into any of my open tabs, their history isn't deleted.

Without restarting the tab or the browser, is there any way to clear the history within a tab?

I also want to know how to clear **just one** tab's history, without needing to know all the pages that the tab had visited, then going to the history page...

Comment: This is something that would need to change the way chrome does history entirely. There probably ins't an extension for this although, one might be made.

Comment: Ref by https://stackoverflow.com/q/46028482/632951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can clear *just one* tab's history, however you can easily clear history for instance of 'The Past Hour' by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

You can also easily launch a new *incognito* window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (Pages you view in this window won't appear in your browser history or search history, and they won't leave other traces, like cookies, on your computer after you close all open incognito windows.)